# Loop through all properties of certain type in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I need to loop through all properties in all node where they are of a certain type for example text string field, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why loop throught the properties when you can get them directly? In umbraco version >= 6 you can do this:

```
UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext);
var root = umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot().FirstOrDefault();
if (root != null)
    var someProperty = root.GetPropertyValue("yourPropertyAlias");
```

In this case I'm getting "yourPropertyAlias" property of my root node.

EDIT - If you want to access a certain node type you can just do this:

```
var certainNodeType = root.Children.Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias.ToLowerInvariant() == "certainNodeType")
```